# callback event.dataTransfer.setData

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

So I want to drag and drop something that takes a little while to process, so I'm using a callback. However my `.dataTransfer.setData` call does nothing then run from the callback. The `dataTransfer.setData` works from `myCallback` just fine, and I know the callback is running from the console log.

Any ideas or suggestions for doing this better?

```
handleDragStart = function(event) {
  var foo = [];
  this.processFoo(foo,myCallback);

  myCallback = function() {
    console.log('running callback')
    var msg = JSON.stringify(foo);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', msg); //won't work
    }

  //event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'test message'); //works if I uncomment it
}

processFoo = function(foo, callback) {
  //pretend this has to talk to some external server and takes a while to respond
  foo.push("bar");
  callback()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope. I get the impression that this is working as intended since it prevents a vulnderability of injecting code into the dataTransfer thingy.

Also, skiing-marmot!? I used to ski marmot all the time! I miss that place :)